# The issue with this SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   $query="INSERT INTO `main_table` (`count`) VALUES ('$count') WHERE userid='$someid'";
```

basically I like to insert a new value of count into the variable count in the main_table where the userid equal to a variable someid.

SQL complains the syntax on this statement.

Comment: Did you want to create a brand new row, or did you want to update some previously stored data? Perhaps, for future visitors, you could edit your question to include the exact error that MySQL gives you.

Comment: Please post your table structure. `SHOW CREATE TABLE main_table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update an existing row you should use an UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT statement.

```
UPDATE `main_table`
SET `count` = '$count'
WHERE userid='$someid'
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ce0a/1)

INSERT is only used for inserting completely new rows into your table. It is not legal to have a WHERE clause on an INSERT statement.

Comment: I got a Unknown column '1' in 'field list' though with that. I double checked all the column names are correct.

Comment: @jasonwhite: I've tested that exact query and it definitely works. See my link to sqlfiddle showing it working online. Maybe your copy + paste key isn't working properly? My guess is that somehow either `$count` or `$someid` ended up surrounded in backticks instead of quotes. Can you post the *exact* SQL that you sent to the database (after the PHP variables were evaluated)?

Answer (score 0):

should be

$query="INSERT INTO main_table (count) VALUES ($count) WHERE userid='$someid'";

single quotes are only used for varchar types variables on varchar type fields.

Rhian A.  (NZT)